# Value of Provider is not resetting when popping away and coming back

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox, provider

Provider file

```
class TermsOfServiceProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _termsOfService = false;

  bool get termsOfService => _termsOfService;

  void termsOfServiceUpdated(bool value) {
    _termsOfService = value;

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Above is the provider I am using.

```
CheckoutButton(
                  onPressed:
                      context.watch<TermsOfServiceProvider>().termsOfService
                          ? () {
                              orderAddressBloc.handleFormSubmit(
                                addressFormValues!.value,
                                customerInfoFormValues!.value,
                                useAsBilling: useAsBillingValue.value,
                                optedIn: optIn.value,
                                termsAndConditions: termsConditions.value,
                              );
                            }
                          : null,
                  blocLoadingIndicator: orderAddressBloc.loadingIndicator,
                ),
```

Above is where I am using the value.

But when I'm popping away from this page and returning the value of `termsOfService` when coming back is not changing.

I am using a checkbox for handling the data validation so when it is true it is activating a button to be clicked and false the button is inactive.

But when I am clicking for it to be true and navigating away and coming back the checkbox is not ticked but the value is `true`, setting the button to active when it shouldn't be.

```
  child: CheckboxListTile(
    value: checkedValue,
    onChanged: (bool? newValue) {
      context
          .read<TermsOfServiceProvider>()
          .termsOfServiceUpdated(newValue!);
      setState(() {
        checkedValue = newValue;
      });
    },
```

Above is the checkbox code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not properly resetting the value of _termsOfService when navigating away and returning to the page. you can fix it by using the didChangeDependencies method in your CheckoutButton widget to reset the value of _termsOfService when the widget is rebuilt.

```
@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    final provider = Provider.of<TermsOfServiceProvid(context,listen:false);
    provider._termsOfService = false;
}
```

This will reset the value of `_termsOfService` to false when the widget is rebuilt, so the checkbox will be unticked and the button will be inactive when the user navigates back to the page.